# MIPS .align # giving same results for different numbers

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm working with MIPS and have wrote a program that takes user integer input and stores the values in an array which will later be printed out in a particular format.

The memory is declared as:

`point_array:`

.align  2
.space  1024

I've also run the program with `.align 4` and the values are stored in memory in the exact same way.  I don't think I fully grasp the effect of `.align` and would like to know why aligning the memory with 2 and 4 produces the same results.

Answer (score 1):

"Align" means that the next address must be a multiple of 2^n. ".align" will insert some dummy bytes to archieve this.

Example: If you insert an ".align 4" instruction at address 0x123400F then one byte is inserted; ".align 1" would also insert one byte.

However if you use the two instructions at address 0x1234012 then ".align 1" would do nothing while ".align 4" would insert 14 bytes.